# Python print date and time with a variable on single line

Tags: python

How would i print the date and time and a variable on the same print line.
I have attempted this code below and it doesn't work.

The first two SomeTexts should be in [] in print

```
print ("[{}][SomeText] - [SomeText] - Some More Text " + myvar + ".format(str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())))
```

Comment: `print("[{}] ... {}".format(datetime.utcnow(), myvar))`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import datetime 
myvar = "myvar text";
print (("[{}][SomeText] - [SomeText] - Some More Text " + myvar).format(str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())))
```

output

```
[2021-08-06 07:57:39.403136][SomeText] - [SomeText] - Some More Text myvar text
```

Comment: Works Perfect. Will mark as answer when it lets me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var1 = 'Hello'
var2 = 'World'
print("{} {}".format(var1, var2))

>> Hello World
```

Just change & add the text around them:

```
print("[{}] [Some text] - More text {}".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), myvar))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you have 2 different ways to do the same thing.
I have renamed datatime as dt for simplicity.

```
import datetime as dt

myvar = "myvar text"
print("[" + str(dt.datetime.now()) + "][SomeText] - [SomeText] - Some More Text " + myvar)
```

OR

```
import datetime as dt

myvar = "myvar text"
print(("[{}][SomeText] - [SomeText] - Some More Text " + myvar).format(str(dt.datetime.now())))
```